# draggable multiplies every time i move it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

why would draggable multiply everytime i move it? i took a picture to show you what i mean. this happens every time i move the helmet image resizing is no problem only when i drag the image here is my script only if you need more please feel free to ask thank you.

```js
 <script>// External added
    jQuery(download).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").hide();
        jQuery(".out-put-img1").hide();
        jQuery("#imajes45").change(function () {
            var selected = jQuery('#imajes45').val();
            if (selected == "new-upload") {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").show();
            } else {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").hide();
            }
        });

        //File
        function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    jQuery(".out-put-img1").show();
                    $('#output1').attr('src', e.target.result);
//                   / $('.append-img').append('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        jQuery("#upload-img1").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
   
 $(".samson").draggable();
$(".out-put-img1").resizable();
 

        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    // External added
    jQuery(download).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper1").hide();
        jQuery(".out-put-img2").hide();
        jQuery("#imajes45").change(function () {
            var selected = jQuery('#imajes45').val();
            if (selected == "new-upload") {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper1").show();
            } else {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper1").hide();
            }
        });

        //File
        function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    jQuery(".out-put-img2").show();
                    $('#output2').attr('src', e.target.result);
//                   / $('.append-img').append('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        jQuery("#upload-img2").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
   
  $(".dragbal1").draggable();
$(".out-put-img2").resizable();
  
  
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    // External added
    jQuery(download).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper2").hide();
        jQuery(".out-put-img4").hide();
        jQuery("#imajes45").change(function () {
            var selected = jQuery('#imajes45').val();
            if (selected == "new-upload") {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper2").show();
            } else {
                jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper2").hide();
            }
        });

        //File
        function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    jQuery(".out-put-img4").show();
                    $('#output4').attr('src', e.target.result);
//                   / $('.append-img').append('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        jQuery("#upload-img4").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
   
 $(".chinass2").draggable();
$(".out-put-img4").resizable();
  

        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: can you add a working jsfiddle or snippet?

Comment: Here is my fiddle but it doesn't work properly I appologies. https://jsfiddle.net/2taya76y/2/

Comment: what element is draggable in the fiddle? the picture doesn't seem like draggable.

Comment: It is the code above  it is made up  of 3 scripts it is at the bottom of every script $(".samson").draggable();
$(".out-put-img1").resizable();
 

        });
    });

Comment: @Aminur Rashid is their a solution to my problem? Do

Comment: in your jsfiddle, no item seems draggable in outpur area.

Comment: Yes once I separated my original code and made a short code for fiddle the code stopped working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132801/discussion-between-xcalliber-and-aminur-rashid).

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this code. I have done some cleaning and tinkering: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/tp5ccf9L/6/ I suspect a lot of issues come from syntax errors, like using `$()` where you will need to use `jQuery()`. Also it seems like you want to allow users to choose to upload an image or select an image, that's not working yet. The image is not appending right, But it is getting there. Think I will create a fork and start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following Demo as a sort of Guide, you can make this work better:

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager

With the idea that the user would want to upload an image and then place it on the shirt, I created an upload preview first. This can then be dragged onto the target shirt. It then needs to be appended to `#boxes`, allowed to be dragged, and resized.

Here is my working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4ezggt9h/

**HTML**

```
<div class="work-wrapper">
  <div id="firstshirt" class="container">
    <div id="boxes" class="container">
      <img id="img-1" src="https://torcdesign.com/shirts/brown.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-wrapper">
    <h3>Controls</h3>
    <a id="btn-Preview-Image" class="button">Preview</a>
    <a id="download" download="my_image.png" class="button disabled" href="#">Download Image</a>
    <select id="imajes45">
      <option value="">Choose Source</option>
      <option value="new-upload">Upload Images</option>
      <option value="select-item">Select Item</option>
    </select>
    <div class="file-upload-wrapper" id="draggableHelper" style="display: none;">
      <input type="file" class="upload-img" name="file1" id="upload-img-1" />
      <div id="upload-preview" class="small upPreview">
        <span>0/3</span>
        <ul id="preview-gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <select name="subselector" class="file-select" style="display: none;">
      <option value="">Choose Gallery</option>
      <option value="bulldog">Bulldogs</option>
    </select>
    <div id="bulldog-gallery" class="upPreview hidden">
      <ul class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif" class="icon" /></li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif" class="icon" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Result:</h3>
<div>
  <div id="previewImage"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .work-wrapper {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
 }

 .work-wrapper:after {
   content: "";
   clear: both;
   display: table;
 }

 .container {
   background-color: transparent;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 2px solid;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   /* Will stretch to specified width/height */
   background-size: 490px 500px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

 .control-wrapper {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 310px;
   width: 310px;
 }

 .control-wrapper h3 {
   padding: 0.2em .4em;
   margin: 0;
 }

 .button {
   background: #f0f0f0;
   border: 2px groove #e3e3e3;
   border-radius: 4px;
   color: #000000;
   display: block;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 13px;
   line-height: 17px;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
   margin: 3px 5px;
 }

 .upPreview {
   border: 2px groove #e0e0e0;
   border-radius: 6px;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 13px;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   height: 142px;
   margin: 5px;
 }

 .upPreview span {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   border-bottom: 2px groove #e0e0e0;
   background: #e0e0e0;
 }

 .upPreview ul {
   width: 100%;
   background: #FFF;
 }

 .upPreview ul li {
   float: left;
   width: 90px;
   height: 110px;
   margin: 0.4em;
   text-align: center;
 }

 .upPreview ul li a {
   float: right;
 }

 .upPreview .icon {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   margin: 5px;
 }

 .hidden {
   display: none;
 }

 .button:hover {
   background: #f0f0ff;
 }

 .disabled {
   border: #606060;
   color: #606060;
 }
```

**JavaScript**

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    console.log("Reading File.");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
      if (jQuery("#preview-gallery li").length == 3) {
        input.value = "";
        return false;
      }
      var $imgP = jQuery("<img>", {
        class: "uploaded-image icon",
        src: reader.result
      });
      var $item = jQuery("<li>", {
        class: "ui-widget-content ui-corner-all hidden"
      });
      $item.append($imgP).append("<a href='#' title='Delete this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete image</a>");
      $item.appendTo(jQuery("#preview-gallery")).show("slow");
      makeDrag($item);
      updatePreviewCount();
    });
    if (input.files[0]) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    } else {
      console.log(" Reader: File Not found.");
    }
    input.value = "";
  }
}

function renderContent() {
  html2canvas(jQuery("#firstshirt"), {
    allowTaint: true,
    logging: true
  }).then(function(canvas) {
    jQuery("#previewImage").append(canvas);
    jQuery("#download").css("display", "inline");
    jQuery("#download").attr("href", jQuery("#previewImage")[0].children[0].toDataURL());
  });
}

function makeDrag(o) {
  o.draggable({
    helper: "original",
    revert: "invalid",
    zIndex: 999
  });
}

function makeResize(o) {
  o.resizable();
}

function addImage($item, $pos) {
  $item.fadeOut();
  var $img = $item.find("img");
  $img.css("width", "80px").css("height", "80px");
  $item.remove();
  updatePreviewCount();
  var $drop = jQuery("<div>", {
    class: "dragbal",
    style: "position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;"
  });
  $drop.append($img);
  $drop.appendTo(jQuery("#boxes")).fadeIn();
  $drop.draggable({
    containment: "#boxes"
  });
  makeResize($drop.find("img"));
}

function updatePreviewCount() {
  var cnt = jQuery("#preview-gallery li").length;
  jQuery(".upPreview span").html(cnt + "/3");
}

jQuery(download).ready(function() {
  // Setup
  jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").hide();
  jQuery(".out-put-img").hide();
  jQuery('.smallimages').hide();

  makeDrag(jQuery("[id$='-gallery'] ul li"));

  jQuery("#boxes").droppable({
    accept: ".gallery > li",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("Drop Pos:", ui.offset);
      addImage(ui.helper, ui.position);
    }
  });

  // Events
  jQuery("#btn-Preview-Image").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    renderContent();
    jQuery("#download").removeClass("disabled");
  });

  jQuery("#download").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return jQuery(this).hasClass("disabled");
  });

  jQuery("#imajes45").change(function() {
    if (jQuery('#imajes45').val() == "new-upload") {
      jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").show();
      jQuery(".file-select").hide();
    } else {
      jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").hide();
      jQuery(".file-select").show();
    }
  });

  jQuery(".file-select").change(function() {
    jQuery(".upPreview").hide();
    jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).val() + "-gallery").show();
  })

  jQuery(".upload-img").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
  });

  jQuery('img').on('click', function() {
    var $img = jQuery("<img>", {
      class: "modal-content",
      src: jQuery(this).attr("src")
    });
    var $drag = jQuery("<div>", {
      class: "imgdrag"
    });
    $drag.append($img);
    /*
    $('#fotos').append('<div class="imgdrag"><img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '"/></div>');
    $('.imgdrag').draggable();
    $('#fotos').droppable();
    $('.modal-content').resizable();
    */
    jQuery("#fotos").append($drag);
    $drag.draggable();
  });
});
```

This may generate more questions than answers. Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate all your help I will see if it works with the rest of my code thank you

Comment: one last question how can i keep the file name? the reason is because i want to keep it so i can upload the image

Comment: @xcalliber if the reader has it, it can be gathered from there. Otherwise it will be a rabbit hole of collection from the input upload field value. Here's the rub, each browser handles the file name differently.